# Is it possible to script out Azure alerts like DB objects

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

As an example in on-prem SQL, I can script out any DB object or alert, make some minor changes, and recreate it. As an example, I can script out an alert or job in our Dev environment, make a change, and create the same job in QA or production to promote it. This is a big time saver when creating monitoring and promoting to higher level environments

Is the same possible in Azure? I've created a few alerts in our dev environment but I don't see a way to one-click script it out to Powershell to quickly promote them to our higher-level Azure SQL environments. Looks like I'll have to recreate them in the portal manually or spend time creating one in PowerShell and then create that one but it's still more time-consuming than our usual on-prem process.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can script Azure alerts using ARM templates and Azure PowerShell for automation and promotion between environments. Use ARM templates to define your alerts and deploy them with PowerShell.

Find below the detailed Documentation:

[Azure Resource Manager documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/)